# Bessel's integral implementation

Tags: matlab, bessel-functions

I'm trying to implement this [integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel.27s_integrals) of Bessel function of the first kind of order n.

[image]

here is what I tried:

```
t = -pi:0.1:pi;
n = 1;
x = 0:5:20;
A(t) = exp(sqrt(-1)*(n*t-x*sin(t)));
B(t) = integral(A(t),-pi,pi);
plot(A(t),x)
```

the plot i'm trying to get is as shown in the wikipedia page.[image]

it said:

> Error using  *  Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in besselfn (line 8) `A(t) = exp(sqrt(-1)*(n*t-x*sin(t)));`

so i tried putting x-5;

and the output was:

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
>
> Error in besselfn (line 8) `A(t) = exp(sqrt(-1)*(n*t-x*sin(t)));`

How to get this correct? what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To present an anonymous function in MATLAB you can use (NOT `A(t)=...`)

```
A = @(t) exp(sqrt(-1)*(n*t-x.*sin(t)));
```

with element-by-element operations (here I used `.*`).

Additional comments:

1. You can use `1i` instead of `sqrt(-1)`.
2. `B(t)` cannot be the function of the `t` argument, because `t` is the internal variable for integration.
3. There are  two independent variables in `plot(A(t),x)`. Thus you can display plot just if `t` and `x` have the same size. May be you meant something like this  `plot(x,A(x))` to display the function `A(x)` or `plot(A(x),x)` to display the inverse function of `A(x)`.

Finally you code can be like this:

```
n = 1;
x = 0:.1:20;
A = @(x,t) exp(sqrt(-1)*(n*t-x.*sin(t)));
B = @(x) integral(@(t) A(x,t),-pi,pi);
for n_x=1:length(x)
    B_x(n_x) = B(x(n_x)); 
end
plot(x,real(B_x))
```

Comment: there are two variables here, x for plot and t for the integration. that's the main problem.

Comment: May you should use a function of two arguments: `A=@(x,t) ...`. Thus you can use something like this: `B=@(x) integral(@(t)A(x,t), ...`. I have corrected my answer.